# How to view simplified history for a file with LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

As written in the git [command line documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log), git has several ways to simplify the history (e.g. `full-history`, `dense`, `sparse` etc.).

On the other hand, when I navigate commits of a file using LibGit2Sharp, e.g. by picking all committs from `master` branch (`repo.Branches["master"].Commits`) and then picking the ones where my file was modified, I receive much more commits than by executing `git log myfile` from a commandline.

So my questions are:

1. Is there any way to access the simplification options in LibGit2Sharp?
2. How to achieve the kind of history entries using LibGit2Sharp that `git log` gives me?